Odd error in a BigQuery SQL Query, looking for an explanation
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    CONCAT(ue.vb_name, ue.b_name) AS Uber_Eats_Slug,
    CONCAT(gh.vb_name, gh.b_name) AS Grub_Hub_Slug,
    FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', CAST(ue.timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)) AS uber_formatted_datetime,
    FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', CAST(gh.timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)) AS grubhub_formatted_datetime
FROM 
    `arboreal-vision-339901.take_home_v2.virtual_kitchen_ubereats_hours` AS ue,
    `arboreal-vision-339901.take_home_v2.virtual_kitchen_grubhub_hours` AS gh

GROUP BY 
    Uber_Eats_Slug, Grub_Hub_Slug, uber_formatted_datetime,grubhub_formatted_datetime
LIMIT 1000;

When this query runs, it only produces one repetitive value for Uber_Hub_Slug and uber_formatted_datetime. How is this possible even when the DISTINCT Function is used, when there is no variable that differs in the data pulled. How to avoid this error and pull the required values? The data reads as it should when run separately for both datasets.

I suspect some JOIN between ue and gh is missed

with out seeing siome data and wanted result we can't see the realtionship between both tables, which could be used to define a JOIN between both tables

DISTINCT means that there will be no two records in the result set whose all columns would match. You have
    DISTINCT 
    CONCAT(ue.vb_name, ue.b_name) AS Uber_Eats_Slug,
    CONCAT(gh.vb_name, gh.b_name) AS Grub_Hub_Slug,
    FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', CAST(ue.timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)) AS uber_formatted_datetime,
    FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', CAST(gh.timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)) AS grubhub_formatted_datetime

and indeed you will not get duplicated results. Sure, parts of your results may be duplicated, so Uber_Eats_Slug and uber_formatted_datetime may be the same in two different records as long as at least another field will not be duplicated.
Your GROUP BY is
GROUP BY 
    Uber_Eats_Slug, Grub_Hub_Slug, uber_formatted_datetime,grubhub_formatted_datetime

which ensures that the four fields will be grouped into. If you wanted to GROUP BY Uber_Eats_Slug, uber_formatted_datetime, then do so. However, the desire seemed to be to group by Uber stuff on the one hand, group by Grub stuff on the other and join the two. You can achieve that by separating the two, having a query for Uber, another for Grub, use them as subqueries and join the two result sets in the way you please.
